# hector_quadrotor: how does quadrotor_simple_controller runs?

Tags: hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone:
In the link http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor_controller?distro=fuerte, it says *Simple Quadrotor Controller* plugin implements the controller of the quadrotor. But I do not understand how it runs as a plugin. It seems that it is not compiled and linked into a node, but Gazebo automatically starts it because quadrotor_simple_controller.urdf.xacro was included somewhere in a launch file.
I wonder if some one can give me an idea of how it runs?
Thank you in advance

Kind Regards
Yucong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76255/hector_quadrotor:-how-does-quadrotor_simple_controller-runs?/) by [yclin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2148/yclin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2013-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki pages of the [hector_quadrotor](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor) stack were a bit outdated, as we moved some plugins from one package to another during the transition from fuerte to groovy to hydro. I am sorry. I updated the wiki a couple of minutes ago.

You will find the simple controller plugin for Gazebo in the [hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor_controller) package now. The plugin does not invoke a real controller that outputs motor voltages, but only generates pseudo forces and torques that make the simulated quadrotor look and behave like a real one.

The [hector_quadrotor_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor_controller) package was originally meant for our more fancy real-time controller also running on the real vehicle, but I have not found the time yet to integrate it in gazebo properly.

Please add comments here if there are further questions.

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2013-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yclin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2148/yclin/) on 2013-10-03**:
Thanks Johannes, it resolve my doubts

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2023-01-26**:
How do I use the packages to autonomously control the hector_quadrotor? Suppose I want it to take off an autonomously explore an unknown map? @[Johannes Meyer}